# Multi-stage YAML Release Pipelines in Azure Devops Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

Is Multi-Stage YAML Release pipeline available in Azure Devops Server 2019? If yes, how to enable and get started?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not supported on Azure DevOps Server 2019 at the moment. You must use Azure DevOps Service.

> To use stages in YAML, make sure the [Multi-stage pipelines experience
>   is turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled).

How to get start and detail steps please refer this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/).

Comment: Where is it documented what versions support Multi Stage pipeline? Because when I go to the link about preview features and then click on "multi-stage pipelines" I get to this page, which lists lots of DevOps Server versions as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml